# Vote to Migrate suggestion: Stack overflow

Tags: feature-request, migration, vote-to-close

Adding a migration option would be useful. If this doesn't exist, only staff can migrate.

Comment: Can you give some examples of questions for which you would want this feature?

Comment: If you search all our sites for [proof assistants](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=proof+assistants) you can see that migration from other sites to here would be a better direction than us trying to send unwanted questions away. --- A good way to implement that is with [Community ADs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-promotion-ads), unfortunately they are [not available during beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754/282094). Such promotion would encourage people to come here or flag existing questions without good answers for migration to here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beta sites (including *public* beta sites) never have migration paths like that. See footnote 2 in the [migration FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> <sup>2</sup> Not every site has selectable migration paths; in particular, beta sites, recently-graduated sites, and Meta Stack Exchange don't have any selectable sites (other than the site's per-site meta, if applicable, and vice versa).

These situations are rare enough that it's fine to flag the question for moderator attention; they (or Stack Exchange staff, for the time being) can migrate questions to anywhere when appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

I generally think this is a bad idea.

The probability of posts that are actually good enough to be migrated instead of just closed on this site is quite small. This is not really a programming site; even though proof assistants function pretty much like programming languages, it's not quite the same and there isn't substantial overlap.

Also, migrations generally aren't that great anyway. In the cases where it is viable, a moderator can just do it; moreover, the user can just repost it themselves which is probably better anyway.

Comment: Yeah - to be honest, adding a migration path now would be fairly premature, even if it did turn out to be a long-term good idea. May be better to wait and see what migration paths come up frequently in practice, and then open them up to everyone if and only if folks want that specific path to be something the community owns, vs. mods.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that this is a good idea, but not **yet**. PA has got off to a good start, and we are able to vote to close questions. Perhaps as the site develops (after it leaves *beta*), this option could be added?